# Как записать в список?

Tags: python, list, pymorphy2

Я провожу анализ текста с помощью pymorphy2. Из анализа я выаскиваю само слово (parse.normal_form) и его часть речи (parse.tag.POS).

Вот что у меня выходит

```
появление NOUN
оон NOUN
быть VERB
обусловить PRTS
целый ADJF
```

Как можно записать все это в список, который содержал много маленьких списков

```
[['появление','NOUN'],['оон','NOUN'],['быть','VERB']]


words = text.split()
pos_tag = []
for word in words:
  parse = morph.parse(word)[0] 
  print(parse.normal_form,parse.tag.POS)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это очень просто сделать, просто создайте пустой список и добавляйте в него список двух значений:

```
words = text.split()
res = []
for word in words:
  parse = morph.parse(word)[0] 
  res.append([parse.normal_form, parse.tag.POS]) 
print(res)
```

Вывод:

```
[['появление','NOUN'],['оон','NOUN'],['быть','VERB']]
```